# Typescript find sum from user input numbers

Tags: input, sum, typescript, addition, variadic

My task: have one input where numbers are separated by commas & the button outputs the sum onto the DOM.

I wasn't confident where to start with this. I think what I have is at least somewhat of a good start... but after searching the web and stackoverflow, I haven't come up with any other ideas.

I am suppose to use an array. Also, a professor noted that my initial start with first adding a class ("class Calculate{...}) was a method I could use, but I've since strayed from it. Not sure at this point if I need to go back to that.

HTML

```
<input id="numbers">
<input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="click">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Typescript

```
function calculate(){

var numbersinput:HTMLInputElement =
    <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('numbersinput');

var numbers:number[] = [parseFloat(numbersinput.value)];

var sum = 0;
for(var i:number = 0; i, numbers.length; i++){
    console.log(numbers[i]);
    sum += numbers[i];
}

var outputElement:HTMLDivElement =
    <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById('output');
outputElement.innerHTML = sum.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, the numbersinput variable is going to have a comma-delimited list of numbers (i.e. "3.0, 2, 1.3"). If this is the case, you can use [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to turn the numbers into an array.

Once you have the numbers in an array, you can run through them in a loop and sum them (also see [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) if you want a challend).

You will probably want to verify that each number in the array is valid before you try to add it to your sum. You can use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to cast the string to a number, then use [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to determine if the number is valid before adding it to the sum.

That should be all you need, I purposely left out the code so you will have to figure that part out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the numbers type in the array is string, so by using `+=` operator you're actually concatenating them, so you might need to cast and check them before.

```js
for (var i: number = 0; i, numbers.length; i++) {
    var num = Number(numbers[i]);
    if (!isNaN(num))
        sum += num;
}
```